# Need a WMI contrast event class similar to Brightness event WmiMonitorBrightnessEvent

Tags: c#, wmi

Using the below code, I could able to get an event when someone changes the brightness in Windows:

```
public static void WindowBrightnessListener()
{
    try
    {
        string queryString = "Select * From WmiMonitorBrightnessEvent";

        string scope = @"\\.\root\WMI";

        // Create a watcher and listen for events
        startProcWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, queryString);
        startProcWatcher.EventArrived += ListenToBrightnessStarted;
        startProcWatcher.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

private static void ListenToBrightnessStarted(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent;
    string brightness = targetInstance.Properties["Brightness"].Value.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Brightness changed :" + brightness);
}
```

How can we get the contrast event similarly? Does any WMI event class exists to get contrast too? Please suggest.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to get the Contrast change value